# calling javascript on rendering views in BackBone js. post-render callback?

Tags: javascript, view, backbone.js

behold, a backbone view render call:

```
render: function() {
  $(this.el).html(this.template({title: 'test'}));  //#1
  this.renderScatterChart();
  return this;
},
```

so, I call a standard render at #1. and then, i call a method [this time, it is a wrapper for charting lib] that looks for a div. the div is rendered by the render call. but at this point, it is not attached to the DOM yet (right?). so the chart call sadly dies.

what is the pattern for this? i'd love hear that there is a post-render callback. i've tried a few hacks around this, and sometimes i get the chart to work, but events don't bind.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

My usual approach for this sort of thing is to use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) with a timeout of zero to arrange for something to happen once the browser gets control again. Try this:

```
render: function() {
    $(this.el).html(this.template({title: 'test'}));

    var _this = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        _this.renderScatterChart();
    }, 0);

    return this;
}
```

Or, if `renderScatterChart` is already bound to the appropriate `this`:

```
render: function() {
    $(this.el).html(this.template({title: 'test'}));
    setTimeout(this.renderScatterChart, 0);
    return this;
}
```

You can also use [`_.defer`](http://underscorejs.org/#defer) if you want to be more explicit about what you're up to:

> **defer** `_.defer(function, [*arguments])`
>
> Defers invoking the **function** until the current call stack has cleared, similar to using **setTimeout** with a delay of 0.

So you could also do it like this:

```
// Assuming that `renderScatterChart` is bound to the appropriate `this`...
render: function() {
    $(this.el).html(this.template({title: 'test'}));
    _(this.renderScatterChart).defer();
    return this;
}

// or if it isn't bound...
render: function() {
    $(this.el).html(this.template({title: 'test'}));

    var _this = this;
    _(function() {
        _this.renderScatterChart();
    }).defer();

    return this;
}
```

Comment: @whatbird: This `setTimeout(..., 0)` trick just sets up a function to be called when your JavaScript is all done and control returns to the browser. So your code will set everything up and add everything to the DOM, then the browser takes over and triggers the delayed function. This trick is a bit of a hack but a useful one.

Comment: The hack is not needed if you insert the view.el into the DOM before run render. I do not like to use setTimeout hack,  following a good flow it is never needed. Check my answer explaining differences running render before insert .el and running after insert. One run crash and the other one works normally, without setTimeout hack. ;)

Comment: @DanielAranda: But that forces the caller to know about the view's implementation details and do non-standard things with your view. So it is a question of which sort of kludge you want (or which one is possible under the local circumstances).

Comment: @muistooshort I agree you, I know that is not mandatory too insert the View's element before render it; I always try to avoid the use of setTimeout, in this case I know that the problem is related to the DOM injection and I shared an example of how to fix it without use the setTimeout hack.

Comment: this worked for me but made me feel unclean. maybe a Backbone.Mixin with a render override would be better to centralize this hack in one place.

Comment: I know this is old, and I'm not aware of what the 'renderScatterChart' is doing. In case someone stumbles upon this, perhaps using this.el as context for your chart rendering would work and could avoid waiting for the actual dom to be rendered.

Comment: @JavierFigueroa: AFAIK, the underlying problem is that the chart needs to know the size or position of the element in question but those values won't be available until after the element has been fully rendered onto the page. So you need to queue up a bit of code that will run after the page has been updated. Similar things pop up when you're using anything (such as Google Maps) that needs to know the size or position of something.

Answer (score 26):

I know this is answered, but thought I would share.  Underscore js has this covered for you with the _.defer function.

```
render: function() {
    $(this.el).html(this.template({title: 'test'}));  //#1
    _.defer( function( view ){ view.renderScatterChart();}, this );
    return this;
},
```

According the the Underscore docs, this is effectively the same thing as the accepted solution.

Answer (score 3):

It is because you run render before .el is inserted into the DOM. Check my self explanatory code(run in a blank page with Backbone.js included):

```
function someThirdPartyPlugin(id){
   if( $('#' +id).length ===0  ){
    console.log('Plugin crashed');
   }else{
    console.log('Hey no hacks needed!!!'); 
   }
}

var SomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    id : 'div1',
    render : function(){
      this.$el.append("<p>Hello third party I'm Backbone</p>");
      someThirdPartyPlugin( this.$el.attr('id') );
      return this;
  }
}); 
var SomeView2 = Backbone.View.extend({
    id : 'div2',
    render : function(){
      this.$el.append("<p>Hello third party I'm Backbone</p>");
      someThirdPartyPlugin( this.$el.attr('id') );
      return this;
  }
}); 

var myView1 = new SomeView();
$('body').append( myView1.render().el );
var myView2 = new SomeView2();
$('body').append( myView2.el );
myView2.render();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just do this (if renderSactterChart operates on a 'jQuery-ized' object):

```
render: function() {
  this.$el.html(this.template({title: 'test'}));  //#1
  this.$el.renderScatterChart();
  return this;
},
```

(this is not the actual DOM element...)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem as you did...with highcharts. I was using Backbone.LayoutManager, and ended up hacking the code to add a postRender callback. Would love to see this as a part of Backbone.js

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the `setTimeout` hack, I think this way is more 'normal':

Just pass the $el element to the function that needs to manipulate elements added by `render()` and then DOM manipulation can be done on $el.

Answer (score 0):

Well this has already been answered, but for future reference I've had this problem a few times. I solved it by adding custom events, in this case it could be something like

```
render: function() {
  $(this.el).html(this.template({title: 'test'}));  //#1

  this.on('someView:append', function() {
      this.renderScatterChart();
  }, this);

  return this;
}
```

And then, when I append the element to the DOM, I trigger it like

```
myView.trigger('someView:append');
```

Now, it's certainly not a beatiful solution. You are adding the responsability of triggering this event to whatever is appending the rendered view to the DOM. Depending on how is your code structured it can fit better or worse. Again, I'm just posting this as a future reference and alternative.

More info: http://backbonejs.org/#Events

Answer (score 0):

This should be done like so:

```
render: function() {
  Marionette.ItemView.prototype.render.apply(this, arguments);
  your code ...
}
```

sample with marionette but idea works for backbone views as well