# backbone.js execute view method when view "inserted" into page

Tags: backbone.js

I am not sure how to achieve this and feel that calling from router "view.executeSomeUIaction()" is not a good idea. Appreciate help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're wanting to execute some code on the view when the view's `el` is added to the DOM?

I have that build in to my Backbone.Marionette framework, with the `Region` object, and I wrote a blog post on that, here: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/12/12/composite-js-apps-regions-and-region-managers/

Note in this post, that I am checking for a `onShow` method and then calling it if it exists. This is the bit that you want to pay attention to. If you add this method to your view, and then use a region object to display your view, this method will be called and you can do whatever you need at that point.

My Marionette framework has the Region object built in to it, or you can copy it out of that blog post: https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is do something when the View is loaded into the page you can do this i hope

```
var contactsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    id: "contactView",
    tagName: "div",
    className: "contacts-container",
    render:function(){
     //render your view
     //now attach the events that don't bubble
     $(this.el).on("load",this.added);
    },
    events: {},
    added: function () {
        alert("View had been added");
    }
});
```

#### JsFiddle to play with

http://jsfiddle.net/qy2Ly/

#### Corrected

http://jsfiddle.net/zRSg3/3/

Comment: @Sean I have added a fiddle for you. It seems delegated events run only for those that bubble. Surprisingly `Load` event does not bubble hence you can't attach it through events hash. Do that after the view is ready in render code

Answer (score 0):

[The approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145680/calling-javascript-on-rendering-views-in-backbone-js-post-render-callback) suggested by mu is too short, is to use a `setTimeout` with a timeout of 0. This works well for me in most circumstances.