# Backbone.js getting callback of render, within the view

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a Backbone app and we have stuff like this:

```
render: function() {

   this.$el.html(_template());

   $('#id').plugin();

   return this;
}
```

The `#id` is from an element that's being rendered.  This only works sometimes, as it can take longer for it to actually insert into dom.

Is there a way within this view, to define a callback or somehow know for sure that the dom has been updated, before calling our `plugin()` function?

Thank you!

Comment: I'd suggest firing an event when rendering is fully complete (which is somewhat dependent on how you're rendering).

Comment: where would I fire that event though? In place of `$('#id').plugin();` or after `render()` is called for the view?

Comment: in place of `..plugin()`, you don't want client code to have to worry about that stuff.  Normally this code should be synchronous so `plugin()` shouldn't be getting called before the `html` call is finished.   Your `_template` method may be doing something that breaks the flow and then the event should be triggered at that point inside of `_template`

Comment: Ok, so I tried using the events, it seems to work better, but probably just due to the additional delay of calling an event, it still occasionally doesn't load after actual dom update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that this:

```
$('#id').plugin();
```

is looking for `#id` inside the DOM but `this.$el` isn't in the DOM yet; so, if `#id` is inside `this.$el`, then `#id` isn't in the DOM either and `$('#id')` will be empty. You want to look for `#id` inside `this.$el` and Backbone provides the [`this.$` shortcut](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar) for that:

> **$ (jQuery or Zepto)** `view.$(selector)`
>
> If jQuery or Zepto is included on the page, each view has a **$** function that runs queries scoped within the view's element. [...] It's equivalent to running: `view.$el.find(selector)`.

So you want to do this:

```
this.$('#id').plugin();
```

If your plugin needs its element to be rendered (perhaps it needs size and position information), then you'll have to kludge around a bit:

1. The caller can call a method on your view after it has added it to the DOM.
2. You can use [`setTimeout(..., 0)` or `_.defer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11926548/479863) to bind the plugin *after* the browser has updated the DOM. This only works if everyone is using the common `x.append(v.render().el)` pattern though.

Answer (score 0):

Symply trigger an event:

```
MyView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function(){
        this.on('view:rendered', this.initPlugin, this);
    },
    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(_template());
        this.trigger('view:rendered', this/*or some useful data*/)
    },
    initPlugin: function(){
        this.$('#id').plugin()//watch on this.$ to apply selector inside this view only
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but give a try

bind it to the view as event , fire it after the view being rendered

```
var viewobject = {};

_.extend(viewobject, Backbone.Events);

viewobject.on("alert", function(msg) {
  $('#id').plugin();
});

object.trigger("alert", "an event");
```