# Invoke jQuery Unobtrusive validation on Backbone.js Views

Tags: jquery, validation, backbone.js, unobtrusive-validation

Validations messages are not getting displayed when dynamically parsing html to be validated with jQuery unobtrusive validation plugin. Js fiddle to display the problem is below

**Jsfiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/R92Yn/2/

```
render: function () {
    var tmpl = _.template(this.template);
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(tmpl);
    this.$el.html(tmpl);
    return this;
},
validateForm: function () {
    //$(this.$el).validate();
}
```

I am trying to display a error message that usernaem is required when clicking validate button. But nothing happens, also after you blur out a js error is visible in the console. So how do i make validation work along with Backbone.js views

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jQuery unobtrusive validation plugin (which is originally built for ASP.Net MVC3) requires that your `input`s are placed inside an `form` element. So if don't have `form` the plugin won't work.

So modify your template to include a form:

```
<script type="text/template" id="loginTemplate">
    <form id="myform">
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" data-val="true" 
               data-val-required="user name required"/>
        <span data-valmsg-for="username" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        <input type="button" id="submit" value="Validate"/>
    </form>
</script>
```

Note: I've also change `data-val-required="true"` to `data-val-required="user name required"` because with the `data-val-required` you specify the error message.

In order to the unobtrusive validation work you need to call `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse` after your Backbone view has been attached to the DOM. To do this [there are multiple ways exits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145680/calling-javascript-on-rendering-views-in-backbone-js-post-render-callback).

One is to use the `_.defer()` function:

```
render: function() {
        var tmpl = _.template(this.template);            
        this.$el.html(tmpl);
        _.defer( function(){ $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(tmpl); });            
        return this;
}
```

Then you can manually trigger the unobtrusive validation with the following code

```
validateForm: function() {
        $("#myform").data('unobtrusiveValidation').validate();
}
```

And finally here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wJV6g/).

Comment: That works +1. Is there a clue as to where (line number, code nuget) i modify the behavior of jQuery unobtrusive validation plugin

Comment: @Deeptechtons What do you want to modify in the plugin?

Comment: default implement requires a Form tag, i can't go on and insert forms to all of my templates. Think about cases where there is only one textbox that needs to be validated, there are a few workarounds but i would like to hack through plugin