# How to convert [object Object] in Backbone to actual data

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, backbone-views, amcharts

I have a function in my Backbone view(file.js) which is populated with a JSON response that's in the below format:-

**Function in Backbone View**:-

```
chart_data: function(){
    var all_stats = this.collection.toJSON();
    $("#page-container").html(this.users_by_loc({
        platform_stats: all_stats,
        graph_data: all_stats.items.slice(0,5) 
        // I want to use the top 5 entries to plot graph
    }));
}
```

**Response** present as part of **all_stats**(from my api call - I'm using Rails on server side):-

```
{
   "items":
   [
       {
           "loc": "Chennai",
           "users": 11707
       },
       {
           "loc": "Hyderabad",
           "users": 4327
       },
       {
           "loc": "Pune",
           "users": 3625
       },....(many more entries)

   ]
}
```

Now, I'm trying to pass the json response present in the **graph_data** parameter(defined in my **Backbone view** above) to a variable called **chartData** which is defined in my **jst.ejs** template(code below) . This variable(chartData) is used by my AM charts JS code to actually plot the graph.

My **jst.ejs** file which has the code to populate the graph data and plot the graph looks like this:-

```
<script>
    var chart;  

    chartData = "<%= graph_data %>"    
    console.log("chartData: ", chartData);

            AmCharts.ready(function () {
                // SERIAL CHART
                chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
                chart.dataProvider = chartData;

                //additional code to help plot the chart  

                chart.write("chartdiv");
            });

</script>

<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 60%; height: 400px;"></div>
```

My **current roadblock** is that when I do..

```
chartData = "<%= graph_data %>"    
console.log("chartData: ", chartData);
```

.. in my jst.ejs template the chartData variable instead of having the actual data as part of **all_stats** (shown_above) returns the following in my firebug console:-

```
chartData: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

How do I **correctly assign** the actual data present in **graph_data** variable(as part of my **backbone view**) to the variable **chartData** present in my **jst.ejs** template to plot the graph ?

Comment: Why are you using a `<script>` inside the template at all? Why not do the JavaScript in JavaScript?

Comment: @muistooshort : I think you have a good point, I didn't think of this earlier. Say I write the logic of drawing the chart in my Backbone view(the js file) itself, would I only have to write `<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 60%; height: 400px;"></div>` in my Backbone template(jst.ejs file) and will this work ?

Comment: Probably. You'd just have to call the chart stuff in your Backbone view at the right time.

Comment: @muistooshort: I'm trying tht, but the problem tht I'm now facing is `chart.write("chartdiv");` present in my Backbone view doesn't recognize the `chartdiv` in the template . Is der a way I can just assign the data as part of my AM charts function 2 the `chart.dataProvider` attribute n implement the remaining stuff 2 draw the chart in my jst.ejs template ? If so, hw do I pass the object tht I'm manipulating within my AM charts function as a parameter to template so that I can use it later 2 draw d graph. With this approach chartdiv will be recognized as part of drawing logic wil b in template.

Comment: If the caller is going to put the view into the DOM right away then look info [`_.defer`](http://underscorejs.org/#defer) or [`setTimeout(..., 0)`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9145790/479863).

Comment: @muistooshort: Just what I needed, it worked :) . Thank you very much. Kindly post your suggestions as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: @muistooshort - The _.defer or the setTimeout func works fine when I **refresh** the page, but since I'm on a single page app, most of my requests are AJAX calls. The chart doesn't load when I'm navigating from another part of my app to the place where the chart is expected to load. Any idea what I could be missing ? When I used console.log,  I see that as part of the AJAX request it enters the function where I'm actually drawing the chart, but the `chartdiv` still remains empty.

Comment: I don't know anything about amchart so I'm mostly making blind guesses.

Comment: @muistooshort - Based on the inputs from this [link](http://www.amcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=9398) I had to comment out the following lines in my Backbone JS view :- `AmCharts.ready(function () {` and `});` . After doing this, the chart showed up appropriately. Please post your answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: You can answer your own questions and accept those answers, you did most of the work after all.

Comment: Okay, you win, I'll write up a proper answer tomorrow :)

Comment: @muistooshort: Thanks :) . I remember this quote from the movie 'A Beautiful Mind', nobody wins.. I believe that applies here as well.. I'm just being fair :). Okay, I hope our comment thread stops soon :), as pretty soon.. sometime we would be warned to redirect this thread to a chat room :)... I've already seen that kind of message earlier related to our ongoing thread.. Cheers!:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mixing "real" JavaScript code in with your templates (i.e. tossing a `<script>` into a template, not simple bits of JavaScript for putting the template together) generally doesn't work out that well. You'll usually have an easier time if you separate the concerns: HTMLish things go in the template, functionality is hooked up in the view.

I'm not that familiar with amChart but many charting (and mapping) libraries will need to know a few important things about their target element before they can do any work. In particular, they'll usually want to know where it is on the page and how big it is and those won't be know until the `<div>` has been rendered to the page. In a Backbone app, that generally won't be true until someone has `render`ed a view **and** appended its `el` to the page:

```
var v = new View;
// We don't know the position or size of anything yet.
v.render();
// We still don't know.
$('body').append(v.el);
// Now the size and position are available but we might have to
// pass control back to the browser first.
```

You're facing the added difficulty of amChart apparently wanting the `id` of something in the DOM that it should draw into:

```
chart.write("chartdiv");
```

But `document.getElementById('chartdiv')` won't return anything useful until after `render` has been called and after someone has done a `x.append(v.el)` (or equivalent).

If you're expecting someone to immediately your view's `el` to the page right after calling `render` then you can queue up some code to run after the browser gets control back (and hence has time to figure out the size and position of things and make `document.getElementById('chartdiv')` do something useful) by using [`setTimeout` with a timeout of zero](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9145790/479863):

```
render: function() {
    var _this = this;
    var chartData = ....

    // Do normal rendering and template stuff.

    setTimeout(function() {
        var chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
        chart.dataProvider = chartData;
        //...
        chart.write("chartdiv");
    }, 0);
    return this;
}
```

You can also use [`_.defer`](http://underscorejs.org/#defer) (which is little more than `setTimeout(..., 1)`) if you want to be a little more explicit about it.

There might be some amChart-specific stuff to deal with but hopefully this will take care of the hard parts.

BTW, that `AmCharts.ready` call you mentioned in the comments probably doesn't work that well with single-page apps because it is probably equivalent to `$(document).ready()` and that only fires when a page is loaded (i.e. only once for the duration of a single-page app). There might be other events you can use instead but you should be able to use the existing Backbone view structure instead of relying on document-ready events.